# Why is my sprite not displaying?

Tags: c++, sfml

I have a simple program where I set the texture of a sprite and change its color, but it won't display. The window is entirely black. Is there something I did not do?

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::Texture texture;
    sf::Sprite sprite;

    texture.create(200, 200);

    sprite.setTexture(texture);
    sprite.setColor(sf::Color(209, 59, 59));

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        window.clear();
        window.draw(sprite);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: perhaps the default texture is pure black, so even setting the color of the sprite does not display anything?

Comment: @BWG Textures don't have functions to manipulate their color.

Comment: there has to be some way to change something about a texture. Maybe you could load it from an `sf::Image` that you changed the color of?

Comment: @BWG It works when I do that.

Answer (score 1):

Setting a color to a sprite while its texture's pixels have no color will not work, because of how `sf::Sprite::setColor()` method works.

From SFML documentation:

> void sf::Sprite::setColor  (   const Color &   color   )
>
> This color is modulated (multiplied) with the sprite's texture. It can be used to colorize the sprite, or change its global opacity. By default, the sprite's color is opaque white.

Multiplying any color against a transparent texture will not change anything in how the Sprite is rendered.

One solution would be to create an image of size 200,200 and setting the image to the desired color, using `sf::Image::create (width, height, color)` constructor, then loading the texture from that image.

Example code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(500,500), "TEST");

    sf::Image image;
    image.create(200,200,(sf::Color(209, 59, 59)));

    sf::Texture texture;
    texture.loadFromImage(image);

    sf::Sprite sprite;
    sprite.setTexture(texture);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        window.clear();
        window.draw(sprite);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```